# How can I allow my users configure custom domains

Tags: node.js, dns, subdomain

I need to allow users of my site provide an optional custom domain to point to my hosting server.

What is the best way to go about this without requesting too much effort from them.

E.g assuming the user wants to point https://www.myawesomeapp.com to my hosting server.

Below is how I want them to create the record

| Type | Host | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CNAME | @ | cname.myapp.io. |

and below is the code I am using on the backend to check if they've created the record and pointed it

```
const dns = require('dns');
function checkRecord(req, res) {
    let userCustomDomain = decodeURIComponent(req.query.domain);
    let defaultAppDomain = decodeURIComponent(req.query.defaultAppDomain);
    dns.lookup(userCustomDomain, 'CNAME', (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log(`Result=${result}`);
            if (result === defaultAppDomain) {
                console.log(`${userCustomDomain} has been pointed to ${defaultAppDomain}`);
            } else {
                console.log(`${userCustomDomain} has not been pointed to ${defaultAppDomain}`);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But even after creating the record it is still not resolving to my hosting server.

Is there anything else I need to do on my own server for theirs to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> E.g assuming the user wants to point https://www.myawesomeapp.com to https://app.dreeeepz.com/afhahfhahfhahfhafhaf

They can’t do that. DNS works at the hostname level. It can’t be used to redirect/map onto to HTTP paths.

Instead have them create a CNAME record pointing to the primary hostname you use for this website. Then have them tell you (e.g. with a settings form) what that CNAME is.

When you app receives a request check what [hostname](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.hostname) it is for and compare that to the list of hostnames configured via the aforementioned form and serve up the right user’s data based on that.

Comment: sorry for the mixup. I have updated my question. What I want is for the user to be able to consume my site while staying on his own site not a redirect

Comment: DNS does not deal in HTTP paths at all.